# Place Autocomplete not working properly Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-places

I have added the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_1_embed_a_placeautocompletefragment_or_a_supportplaceautocompletefragment) to my app but when I touch the search button it comes and then disappearing. I couldn't type in the search it disappearing. Disappearing means there's search bar but if we touch googles search bar will come out and we can type there. But It's coming and then it suddenly disappears.

This is the code in XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <fragment
         android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: instead of Fragment why U didn't use `AutoCompleteAdapter` and bind it with Place API?

Comment: @stutikasliwal  documentation doesn't prescribe it..

Comment: ok, well to understand your code and its problem you have to share activity code as well. using Autocomplete along with Place API will be more convenient and easy to implement, You can try it once

Comment: @stutikasliwal I know it very well but the problem is not that  I have the problem with disappearing when I clicked the search button. It means another pop-up search button will come and it will ask that's automatically disappearing in a second.  This image will give some idea about the auto complete .https://developers.google.com/places/images/acw_overlay.png

Comment: I still have this problem, and I do have the API key in the manifest file.
Did you solve the problem? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working and Android API key should be added to the manifest! So it will work !https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/﻿

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. What caused my problem was the api I was using was old and wasn't registered for an android project. 
So I registered a new project here https://console.developers.google.com
and replaced the old api with the new one. Then it worked.

So basically, what was happening was that when you try to search, the api gets refused by google's servers, so it prevents you from searching.