# firebase login not working in flutter android app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Everything was working good yesterday with firebase auth, today it gives me that error.

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(19191): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@138591a
W/DynamiteModule(19191): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(19191): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth(19191): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/flutter (19191): PlatformException(exception, An internal error has occurred. [ Requests from this Android client application are blocked. ], null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712425/google-place-api-requests-from-this-android-client-application-com-package-name) as per your error;

> Requests from this Android client application com.joycustomers.joybank
>   are blocked.

You'd need to check for two things;

1. Your SHA1 signing certificate key being used is correct and listed in the Firebase Console's project settings.
2. You should have the freshest copy of google-services.json from Firebase Console's project settings where you add signing certificate keys. There's a download google-services.json button. Always use the freshest copy whenever you've changed Firebase settings. Read more [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en#android).

**Update:**

OP had updated his Firebase Project settings by changing from Free to Pay as You Go payment plan. This changed his Firebase Project settings and a fresh copy of google-services.json form the Firebase Console fixed the issue.

Comment: i have update the SHA1 signing certificate key but the same error

Comment: Have you published this app before on the Play store?

Comment: Okay, you need to make sure you've added the same SHA1 key from your Google Play Console into your Firebase Console project settings; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254327/published-app-not-working-with-firebase-authentication/55254353#55254353

Comment: I did it and the problem not with published version it with debug version and i add also SHA1 debug to firebase

Comment: Okay. Did you download a new copy of google-services.json from Firebase Console and attached it with your project and rebuild the apk (after adding the SHA1 keys to Firebase Console)?

Comment: No it was there already from long time and everything was fine same device same pc same SHA1 everything was fine until today

Comment: See, whenever you do any changes to the Firebase Console you need to get a new copy of the google-services.json file, attach this newer version to your project and recompile it. Try with a new download of the google-services.json file and see if the new apk works.

Comment: I did something but i don't know if that the problem or not
i have changed the plan from free to pay as you go

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: i have changed the plan from free to pay as you go

Comment: That might change your settings, anyways, try to download a new copy of your google-services.json from Firebase console and replace your old one in project files and then rebuild the app. Try it and see.

Comment: It's working? Good. If it's helped you, kindly accept my answer and upvote my linked answer too as it's related and will help visibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get SHA1 first by command
   goto your `.android` folder mine path is and command is as following

   ```
   C:\Users\lenovo\.android>keytool -list -v -keystore     
   "C:\Users\lenovo\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
   ```

and then

2. Add it to your `firebase.console.com`
3. And download the `google-services.json` file and put in `android/app` folder

if problem is occuring same
then you have to add your support email in firebase
[image]
add support email